# What do these 2 lines of code actually do?

Tags: ruby

I don’t know Ruby but I need to understand how the input value is manipulated in the lines below.

I think that the input is converted to the sum of the values of its characters but the second line is confusing; does it take the final value of the sum and perform the bitwise operations or per iteration? Could you provide a simple explanation of the steps followed?

Thank you in advance!

```
input.to_s.each_char.inject(0) do |sum, ch|
    (sum << 8) ^ (ch.ord) ^ (sum >> 4)
```

Comment: Is it a checksum? A hash?

Comment: You need to tell us what `input` is. Not just its class (`Integer`?), but more generally what it represents. We also need to understand how the return value of your code is used (related to @matt's question, which you need to answer). Lastly, you need a third line of code containing just `end`. Please address these issues by editing your question rather than by elaborating in comments.

Comment: You have selected an answer that does nothing more than explain how `inject` works, with no reference to the particular calculation you wish to perform. There are thousands of explanations of `inject/reduce` within easy reach, many with greater detail than the explanation contained in the selected answer,. That show of laziness earns a downvote from me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It does give me the information I needed under, "So in your case:".

Comment: That may be, but it's not at all clear from the question what you want. Judging from the voting I don't seem to be alone in my assessment of the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is the same as reduce,  and is similar to reduce in many other languages.

There are a number of different ways to call it but the way shown in the question is this:

```
inject(initial) { |memo, obj| block } → obj
```

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is
>   passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a
>   symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to
>   the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new
>   value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo
>   is the return value for the method.
>
> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the
>   first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

So in your case:

```
input.to_s.each_char.inject(0) do |sum, ch|
    (sum << 8) ^ (ch.ord) ^ (sum >> 4)
end
```

The initial value of sum is 0, which is used for the first iteration, but for each subsequent iteration the result of the block is used for sum in the next iteration.

For example the following should produce the same value without using inject/reduce.

```
sum = 0
input.to_s.each_char do |ch|
    sum = (sum << 8) ^ (ch.ord) ^ (sum >> 4)
end
```